# Configuring Symfony2.4 security.yml to use custom authenticator

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, configuration

I am trying to configure my Symfony2.4 application to use a custom authenticator to check a database table to protect against brute force login attempts and I am running into a problem where when a user gives the correct credentials, they are re-directed back to the login screen instead of to their given URL. Here is my security.yml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Acme\FakeBundle\Entity\User: sha512
        Acme\FakeBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_VENDOR: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_STANDARD: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_STANDARD, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        users:
            id: my_custom_user_provider

    firewalls:
        assets_firewall:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js|media|img)/
            security: false
        registration_area:
            pattern: ^(/register|/register/details|/register/success)$
            security: false
        unsecured_area:
            pattern: ^(/login(?!_check$))|^(?!support).privacy|^(?!support).terms_and_conditions
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            simple_form:
                authenticator: my_custom_authenticator
                check_path:    /login_check
                login_path:    /login
                username_parameter: form[_username]
                password_parameter: form[_password]
                csrf_parameter: form[_token]
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, requires_channel: %force_channel% }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel:%force_channel%}
```

Here is my custom User Provider:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FakeBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;
use Acme\FakeBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class AcmeFakeUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{


    /**
     * Holds the Doctrine entity manager for database interaction
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * Fake bundle User entity repository
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    protected $user_repo;

    /**
     * Fake bundle FloodTableEntry repository
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    protected $flood_table_repo;

    protected $container;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->user_repo = $this->em->getRepository("AcmeFakeBundle:User");
        $this->flood_table_repo = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeFakeBundle:FloodTableEntry');
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->request = $this->container->get('request');
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $q = $this->user_repo
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('LOWER(u.username) = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', strtolower($username))
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery();

        try {

            /*
             * Verify that the user has not tried to log in more than 5 times in the last 5 minutes for
             * the same username or from the same IP Address. If so, block them from logging in and notify
             * them that they must wait a few minutes before trying again.
             */
            $qb2 = $this->flood_table_repo->createQueryBuilder('f');
            $entries = $qb2
                ->where($qb2->expr()->eq('f.ipAddress', ':ipAddress'))
                ->andWhere($qb2->expr()->gte('f.attemptTime', ':fiveMinsAgo'))
                ->setParameters(
                    array(
                        'fiveMinsAgo' => date('o-m-d H:i:s',time() - 5 * 60),
                        'ipAddress' => $this->request->getClientIp(),
                    )
                )->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

            if (count($entries) >= 10) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Too many unsuccessful login attempts. Try again in a few minutes.");
            }


            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $q->getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AcmeFakeBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->user_repo->find($user->getId());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return 'Acme\FakeBundle\Entity\User' === $class
        || is_subclass_of($class, 'Acme\FakeBundle\Entity\User');
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the custom authenticator:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FakeBundle\Services;

use Acme\FakeBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class AcmeFakeAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $container;

    private $encoderFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Acme\FakeBundle\Services\FloodTableManager
     */
    protected $floodManager;

    /**
     * Holds the Doctrine entity manager for database interaction
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
        $this->floodManager = $this->container->get('acme.fakebundle.floodtable');
        $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.fakebundle_entity_manager');
        $this->request = $this->container->get('request');
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            $this->floodManager->addLoginFailureToFloodTable($token->getUsername(), $this->request->getClientIp());
            $this->floodManager->trimFloodTable();
            throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $passwordValid = $this->encoderFactory
            ->getEncoder($user)
            ->isPasswordValid(
                $user->getPassword(),
                $token->getCredentials(),
                $user->getSalt()
            );

        if ($passwordValid) {

            // If User is not active, throw appropriate exception
            $status = $user->getStatus();

            if (!$status == User::USER_ACTIVE) {

                // If User's account is waiting on available seats, print this message:
                if ($status == User::USER_PENDING_SEAT) {
                    throw new AuthenticationException("Account pending activation");
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, User's account is inactive, print this error message.
                    throw new AuthenticationException("Account inactive");
                }
            }

            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        }

        $this->floodManager->addLoginFailureToFloodTable($user->getUsername(), $this->request->getClientIp());
        $this->floodManager->trimFloodTable();

        throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }
}
```

When a user gives incorrect login credentials it is handled correctly (i.e. the correct AuthenticationException is thrown with the correct message). However, as mentioned above, if the correct credentials are given then the user simply stays on the login page with no error message being shown.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question but it will help you solve the problem.http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/03/symfony2-security-enhancements-part-ii/

Comment: @user2268997 This is not a duplicate of the question you linked -- that question asks how Symfony redirects the user once they have been authenticated, and deals with post authentication listeners. This question asks why the authentication is not happening properly using my custom authenticator. Furthermore, the referenced question uses a form_login key rather than a simple_form key as I do in defining the user provider, handlers, etc used in authentication. Though the questions are tangentially related, I really don't think this one is a duplicate.

Comment: @user2268997 My team is launching our project on Monday, so if you could remove your incorrect duplicate flag ASAP it would be much appreciated. Also, thank you for your resource in your first comment. Unfortunately, for various reasons this is the approach we'd like to take, so if anyone can think of a solution to my problem using the above approach, that would be great.

Comment: @user2268997 As it turned out, I managed to implement the features I needed using your resource above, so thank you again! That being said, I think we should leave this post open as the approach I'm taking here, as mentioned above, is quite different than using listeners and redirecting users after being successfully authenticated.

Comment: yes you're right.I removed it.Glad to hear you fixed it.However the way you asked it, led me to believe that the problem was only with the redirection not the authentication itself.since you gave no indication of the authentication, itself being faulty.

Comment: True indeed. I'll try to be more clear in the future, and thanks again for the resources. I hope someone is able to answer this eventually, I'm curious to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Then vote the question up! ;-)

Comment: I did, so please edit it and clarify things a bit.e.g: is the token being set?have you tested the authenticator and does it return the token?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer the problem is your regex in `unsecured_area`.`^/login_(?!check$)`
does match "login_check".the dollar sign should be after the parantheses as in `(?!_check)$`.What's currently happening is the login_check path falls under the unsecured_area firewall and the token isn't set for the context of `Secured_area`.Actually I don't think it's kept anywhere since `security: false` for `unsecured_area`.read up on the firewall context in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls